# Grid and Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]

I want to sort the card post by each row have column 3. but When I entered the code in `style={{""}` is not working.

And then, I'm using the `Ant-Design`. Please help how can I solve this?.

```js
props.list.map(result => (
    <div key={result.id}>
        <Row className="gutter-example" gutter={16}>
            <Col className="gutter-row" span={6}>
            <Card hoverable style={{ width: 200 }} cover={ result.volumeInfo.imageLinks ? <img alt="BookCover" src={result.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail} />:
            <img alt="Alternative_Cover" src={AlterNative} />
            }
            >
            <Meta title={result.volumeInfo.title} description={ <a href={result.volumeInfo.infoLink}>
            {result.volumeInfo.infoLink}
            </a>
            }
            />
            </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </div>
```

Comment: A little guess here.The problem is the Card.Add Card into Col,and the span won't work.

Comment: Haha Thanks for your opinions but it works;;

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Ant Design but I though `<Row />` component is wrapper and it should wrap all your `<Col />`

So, if you want to render 3 items in each, you should render all `<Col span={6} />` in `<Row />` component. Each `<Row />` is mean fullwidth container.

```
<Row>
     {list.map(item => <Col key={item.id} span={6}><Card /></Col>)}
</Row>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list component and add grid={{gutter:16,column:3}} to its props